# Can I set a header with python's SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: python, cross-domain, simplehttpserver

I'm using `SimpleHTTPServer` to test some webpages I'm working on.  It works great, however I need to do some cross-domain requests.  That requires setting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the domains the page is allowed to access.

Is there an easy way to set a header with SimpleHTTPServer and serve the original content?  The header would be the same on each request.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack because it changes `end_headers()` behavior, but I think it's slightly better than copying and pasting the entire `SimpleHTTPServer.py` file.

My approach overrides `end_headers()` in a subclass and in it calls `send_my_headers()` followed by calling the superclass's `end_headers()`.

It's not 1 - 2 lines either, less than 20 though; mostly boilerplate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    from http import server # Python 3
except ImportError:
    import SimpleHTTPServer as server # Python 2

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()

        server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def send_my_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.test(HandlerClass=MyHTTPRequestHandler)
```

Comment: Also don't forget to send the headers if you are redefining do_GET:  `def do_GET(self):
    self.send_head()`

Comment: This solution doesn't work if using the default do_GET(). It does not call end_headers.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say there's no simple way of doing it, where simple means *"just add 1-2 lines that will write the additional header and keep the existing functionality"*. So, the best solution would be to subclass the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class and re-implement the functionality, with the addition of the new header.

The problem behind why there is no simple way of doing this can be observed by looking at the implementation of the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class in the Python library: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/19c74cadea95/Lib/http/server.py#l654

Notice the `send_head()` method, particularly the lines at the end of the method which send the response headers. Notice the invocation of the `end_headers()` method. This method writes the headers to the output, together with a blank line which signals the end of all headers and the start of the response body: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers

Therefore, it would not be possible to subclass the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` handler, invoke the super-class `do_GET()` method, and then just add another header -- because the sending of the headers has already finished when the call to the super-class `do_GET()` method returns. And it has to work like this because the `do_GET()` method has to send the body (the file that is requested), and to send the body - it has to finalize sending the headers.

So, again, I think you're stuck with sub-classing the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class, implementing it exactly as the code in the library (just copy-paste it?), and add another header before the call to the `end_headers()` method in `send_head()`:

```
...
self.send_header("Last-Modified", self.date_time_string(fs.st_mtime))
# this below is the new header
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
self.end_headers()
return f
...
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, I was looking for the one or two line solution.

Copying the method is the next best solution though

Comment: Then it shouldn't provide self.send_header() and self.end_headers() API to the public as all it does is to confuse consumer developer. The headers are indeed added to response body.

Answer (score 5):

```
# coding: utf-8
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
PORT = 9999

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://example.com')           
    self.end_headers()

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.do_GET = do_GET
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I guess I should be more clear in that I still want to serve the original content, but with the additional header, not just the header alone.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an older answer, its the first result in google...

Basically what @iMon0 suggested..Seems correct?..Example of `doPOST`

```
def do_POST(self):
    self.send_response()
    self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    self.end_headers()
    sTest = {}
    sTest['dummyitem'] = "Just an example of JSON"
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(sTest))
```

By doing this, the flow feels correct..

1: You get a request

2: You apply the headers and response type you want

3: You post back the data you want, be this what or how ever you want.,

The above example is working fine for me and can be extended further, its just a bare bone JSON post server. So i'll leave this here on SOF incase someone needs it or i myself come back in a few months for it.

**This does produce a valid JSON file** with only the sTest object, Same as a PHP generated page/file.

Comment: I guess the original question could be more clear, but what I wanted was a simple way to serve content from a directory for dev purposes, and add a header to allow cross origin requests.

My ideal would have been something like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer --header=Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  That's not possible, so you end up having to implement some code to do it.

You can of course extend `SimpleHTTPServer` to do many other things.

Comment: You should be able to post the header from within the served content? Otherwise PHP now offers it own webserver so you dont need to install apache. Allows you to fire it up with a directory and nothing more. As long as you found a solution

Comment: `self.send_response` will lead to an error. 1)It's a function so it's actually `self.send_response()` and 2)that function always requires you to pass a value for the `code` argument.

Comment: `self.send_response` = Typo.