# Python - Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: jquery, python, server

I am new to python and I am trying to fetch data from a python script using http request through jquery ajax call. However, I am getting the below error as the python script does not allow cross domain request.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://somehost.com:8000/gen.py. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I am not sure what do I need to change in the below script to server cross domain request. To be clear, I am using python v2.6.6 which is installed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago). Below is the python server code that I have tried so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Here is the jquery code from a html file which is located on different server:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({          
          url: "http://somehost.com:8000/gen.py",
          type: 'GET',        
          success: function(data) {             
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(e) {          
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Any pointer to this is appreciable. Let me know if I should provide any more details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your infrastructure? How is the javascript served? Are you not using python on your web app?

Comment: @e4c5 the python script is located on linux box

Comment: That's not what I am asking. I am asking if your javascript is on one web server and your python script is on another

Comment: @e4c5 Yes, The javascript and python script are located on different servers

Answer (score 0):

As e4c5 mentioned, you need to make a CORS request. Since the jquery isn't being served from the same server that is providing `gen.py`, you need a header on the python server side to allow the browser to retrieve the resource. This [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is to prevent cross-site scripting.

To do so with BaseHTTPServer, you're going to need to redefine the request handler and provide a call to `self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583827/cors-with-python-basehttpserver-501-unsupported-method-options-in-chrome) shows how to do it with BaseHTTPServer, but it's fairly long and involved.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499171/can-i-set-a-header-with-pythons-simplehttpserver) has a pretty simple implementation of how to set the CORS header on SimpleHTTPServer, which has a similar structure to BaseHTTPServer which you can pretty easily port over.

*Regarding the `*` in the `send_header` call, this allows requests from any origin to get `gen.py`. Depending on what this is, it may not matter but you may want to set a more restrictive policy if it does.